# PHP ob_get_clean removing newlines after ?>

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that grabs a script file and executes the output on a telnet device. I have it working, but ob_get_clean seems to be removing any newlines after a php closing brace (?>). Has anyone encountered this problem?

```
public final function execScript($name, $args)
{
    ob_start();
    include("../apps/frontend/modules/device/scripts/" . $name . ".php");
    $partial = ob_get_clean();
    $commands = explode("\n", $partial);

    foreach($commands as $command)
    {
        $output .= $this->telnet->exec($command);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

"Script"

```
conf
int ethernet 1/<?php echo $args['port']; ?>
switchport allowed vlan add <?php echo $args['vlan_id']; ?> tagged
switchport native vlan <?php echo $args['vlan_id']; ?>
switchport allowed vlan remove 1
end
```

Expected Output

```
conf
int ethernet 1/18
switchport allowed vlan add 100 tagged
switchport native vlan 100
switchport allowed vlan remove 1
end
```

Actual Output

```
conf
int ethernet 1/18switchport allowed vlan add 100 tagged
switchport native vlan 100switchport allowed vlan remove 1
end
```

Comment: Perhaps try `$partial = eval(file_get_contents(PHP_FILE))`

Answer (score 3):

**One newline will always be ignored after a closing `?>` tag** -- using output buffering doesn't change anything.

As a reference, see [**Instruction separation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) :

> The closing tag for **the block will include the immediately trailing
>   newline** if one is present.

And [**Escaping from HTML**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) :

> when PHP hits the `?>` closing tags, it simply starts outputting
>   whatever it finds (**except for an immediately following newline** - see
>   instruction separation )

According to those two sentences from the PHP manual *(and from my own experience)*, losing a newline after the `?>`, like you do, is documented and expected behavior<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1.</sup><sub>Even if surprising, the first time you encounter it ^^</sub>

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? Or am I stuck making my own parser with str_replace?

Comment: I don't think there's a way arround this *(except using some specific templating engine)* : this is the behavior of PHP, and there is no kind of setting directive to change that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PHP does that - it removes one single newline after the ?>

It does that because in a normal PHP file, you close it with ?> then you have a trailing newline which would often mess things up.

In your case, it's not helping.

I would do this:

```
conf
int ethernet 1/<?php echo $args['port'] . "\n";
?>switchport
```

I moved the closing ?> to the next line just so you are not depending on newline removal.